# Eclipse - Assigning each main method to a separate console

Tags: java, eclipse, console, program-entry-point

I'm currently writing a program and I was wondering if it's possible for eclipse to open up separate consoles automatically for each main when I run the following main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    object1.main(args);
    object2.main(args);
    object3.main(args);
    object4.main(args);
}
```

My current solution is to run each main method and select the appropriate one to view within the "Display Selected Consoles" option although it's a very tedious process everytime I want to test my program out. I'd be very grateful for any suggestions you have.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. The purpose of my program is to simulate a server and multiple clients communicating to one another. Therefore object1 would be the starting of a server object and object2 onwards are starting clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do multiple calls to your `main` method from within another `main` method, this will not be different from calling any other static method multiple times. Particularly, all those instances of your program will be executed in the same JVM.

Instead, you could use a simple [Ant script](https://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) to start multiple instances of your program, for example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Test" default="run_external">
    <target name="compile">
        <delete dir="bin" />
        <mkdir dir="bin" />
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="bin" />
    </target>
    <target name="run_many" depends="compile">
        <parallel>
            <java classname="test.Main" classpath="bin" />
            <!-- copy-paste 'java' block for more instances -->
        </parallel>
    </target>
    <target name="run_external" depends="compile">
        <parallel>
            <exec executable="xterm" dir="bin">
                <arg value="-e" />
                <arg value="java test.Main" />
            </exec>
            <!-- copy-paste 'exec' block for more instances -->
        </parallel>
    </target>
</project>
```

This script defines three *targets* -- which of them is executed is determined in the `default` parameter.

- The first target, `compile`, just invokes `javac` to build all the sources in the `src` directory. This is automatically executed before any of the other targets are run.
- The second target, `run_many`, simply starts your Main class several times in parallel. Each instance will run in a separate JVM, but the output of all those instances will be mixed up in Eclipse's console window.
- The third target, `run_external`, starts an `xterm` terminal emulator running the respective Java processes, i.e. for each instance of your program a new terminal should pop up. (When doing this on Windows you may have to use `cmd.exe` or similar.)

Not sure whether this is what you were looking for. Hope this helps.

Comment: Appreciate the detailed response. I have tried out the latter run_external part of your code in eclipse on a simple helloworld program and it works given that I use javac on the .java main beforehand. Problem is when I run this on eclipse, it only runs on the console and not command prompt when I changed the executable to "cmd". It seems to write out the output from cmd onto the eclipse console. Also if I am to use this for my real program, would I have to write the ant script to include the javac command per class I have?

Comment: @user1087943 I thought Eclipse would take care of building the files... nevermind, I've added another target for that. This will build all your classes at once before invoking the other targets. About the problem with `cmd`: I'm afraid I can't help you here, except assuring you that it works using `xterm` or any other Linux terminal emulators I've tried.

Comment: Eclipse does build the files but they're within its own folder away from the .java files. For the ant file to work, I had to move the .class files next to the .java files. The code you've added seems to be doing what eclipse is already doing - compiling the .class files and storing them in the bin folder. Would ant be able to associate the .class files in the bin folder with the .java files in the src folder?

Comment: @user1087943 Well, I guess you could set `javac destdir` to `src`. However, using `classpath=bin` and `dir=bin` the script should run the way I've posted it (at least it does run for me). Where have you placed the script, and how do you invoke it? It should be in the Eclipse project and be invoked by _right-click -> run as ant script_.

Comment: Your code works fine now. It was because I changed the dir attribute to "src" which meant I had to compile the .java files in that directory. I'll have another look round for the cmd problem. Many Thanks for the help!